# Passing BufferedReader as a parameter of a constructor of a class

Tags: sockets, networking, bufferedreader, socketexception

I have set up a network and I've set up the reading and writing stream to a socket as so:

```
//Set up socket reads and writes
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
    client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

I wanted to pass the two variables, 'in' and 'out', as parameters of another class' constructor. This is how it looks in the other class

```
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

public ClientThread(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;

}
```

I then wanted to use those class variables to write to the output stream of the same socket like this (the class implements Runnable):

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            String userCommand = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Die if something goes wrong.
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, whenever the code gets to this point, I get a SocketException:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

How can I fix this? I want to separate the setting up of the server and the socket from the processing of any commands given by the client.

---

EDIT: Here's what the BufferedRead gets the input from

```
//create server socket
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(portNum);

// Accept a client if it appears
Socket client = server.accept();
```

---

EDIT 2: I used these three files:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        //Change the socket if it doesn't work
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 5920);

        //keyboard
        final BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //input from socket
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

        //writer to socket
        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                sock.getOutputStream(), true);

        //new thread for incoming messages
        (new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String serverMessage;

                try {
                    while ((serverMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(serverMessage);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Something went wrong whilst trying "
                            + "to retrieve a message from the server");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        }).start();

        //new thread for outgoing messages
        (new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String clientMessage;

                try {
                    while ((clientMessage = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.println(clientMessage);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Something went wrong whilst trying "
                            + "to send a message to the server.");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }

            }

        }).start();

    }

}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5920);

        Socket client = server.accept();

        //Set up socket reads and writes
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                client.getOutputStream(), true);

        new Thread(new ClassWithParam(in, out)).start();

    }

}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class ClassWithParam implements Runnable {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public ClassWithParam(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("HERE");
                String userCommand = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("HERE2");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Die if something goes wrong.
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And now it works. Don't know what happened. Will proceed to bang head against wall. Thanks.

Comment: Well presumably the connection has been closed. That has nothing to do with the use of a BufferedReader within a constructor. We can't really help you at the moment given that we know *nothing* about what the connection is to.

Comment: Does this help? //create server socket
   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(portNum);
   
   // Accept a client if it appears
   Socket client = server.accept();

Comment: Not really... we still don't have enough context, and all the information should be in the *question* rather than in comments. Ideally, you should show a short but complete program (or more likely a pair of programs) which we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hold on I'll put something together

Comment: @JonSkeet the problem just disappeared when I recreated the code (which is in the question) and now I hate myself.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there's no problem now. The code (I recreated) which I used, which now works, is in the description.